Зависают контейнеры Docker
У меня большая проблема с  докер контейнерами, они зависают, как только начинается нагрузка более чем в 10 запросов в секунду (примерно). И я и мои коллеги уже испробовали много методов диагностики, и не нашли проблему.
Зависает и FastAPI контейнер при нагрузке от юзеров. И Aiogram Python бот, когда начинаю делать рассылку. Такая же проблема есть и на других моих проектах, где совершенно другая архитектура, но так же используется Docker.
Я пытался выделять максимум ресурсов, но докер не использует их все и просто зависает. Я пытался делать репликацию контейнеров, но и это не помогает.
Никаких данных докер в логи не пишет, нигде не отображает, что контейнер завис. Он просто зависает, перестает отвечать на команды, вести логи, приложение падает, а контейнер даже убить нельзя. Приходится перезагружаться systemctl docker на сервере полностью.
Compose file:
version: '3.3'

services:
  bot:
    image: "bot"
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    build:
      context: .
    working_dir: "/usr/src/app/bot"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/bot
    command: python3 -m bot
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"

  pg_database:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: "postgres -c max_connections=1500
             -c shared_buffers=768MB -c effective_cache_size=2304MB
             -c maintenance_work_mem=128MB -c checkpoint_completion_target=0.9 -c wal_buffers=16MB
             -c default_statistics_target=100 -c random_page_cost=1.1 -c effective_io_concurrency=200
             -c work_mem=16MB -c min_wal_size=1GB -c max_wal_size=4GB -c max_worker_processes=2
             -c max_parallel_workers_per_gather=2 -c max_parallel_workers=2 -c max_parallel_maintenance_workers=1
             -c log_min_duration_statement=5000 -c log_connections=on -c log_disconnections=on"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"

  pgbouncer:
    image: edoburu/pgbouncer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DB_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - DB_HOST=pg_database
      - MAX_CLIENT_CONN=500
      - DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE=20
    volumes:
      - ./pgbouncer:/etc/pgbouncer
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/pgbouncer", "/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini" ]

  redis_cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --port $REDIS_PORT --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    volumes:
      - cache:/data

  api:
    image: "api"
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    build:
      context: ./infrastructure/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: "/usr/src/app/api"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/api
    command: "uvicorn infrastructure.api.app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1.0"
          memory: "700M"
        reservations:
          cpus: "1.0"
          memory: "700M"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.nginx
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
      - ./images:/var/www/html/images
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
  cache: {}

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/bot

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

FastAPI DockerFile:
FROM python:3.11-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/api
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/api


Почему вы решили, что проблема с контейнерами, а не с кодом ваших проектов?

Ну и да, что такое «контейнер даже убить нельзя», почему нельзя? / «приложение падает» — если логов и прочего нет, то тогда откуда вы знаете что падает?

Если «Такая же проблема есть и на других моих проектах», то это намекает, что должно быть возможно составить [mcve]

А, ну и ещё dmesg почитайте, чтобы исключить (или наоборот подтвердить) проблемы с оборудованием. Я наблюдал у себя рандомные зависания чего попало, когда подкачка находилась на полумёртвом диске, например

@andreymal потому что запускали почти голый проект для теста и тоже все зависало. И несколько человек проверяло код ,с ним все ОК. Но я уже ни в чем не уверен, просто неуловимый баг.

Ну и да, что такое «контейнер даже убить нельзя», почему нельзя? / «приложение падает» — если логов и прочего нет, то тогда откуда вы знаете что падает? "
Знаю что падает, т.к оно перестает работать, сайт не открывается.

Из "сайт не открывается" никак не следует "приложение падает", не открываться может по куче разных причин, в том числе неоднократно упомянутому вами зависанию (причём зависанию даже не приложения, а например сетевого стека докера, если в нём вдруг баг какой-нибудь)

Если проект действительно "почти голый", значит его должно быть возможно добавить в вопрос, чтобы мы попробовали запустить его у себя и нагрузить чем-нибудь

Спасибо. Был голый 3 мес назад ,на проде, с нагрузкой, сейчас уже с компоузом выше - большой, но так же виснет. Эта проблема только на проде появляется, когда есть нагрузка от юзеров. Чем посоветуете нагружать, чтобы было похоже на юзеров? Пробовал запросы к апи (они чаще кладут проект) через Postman.

Чем угодно, что умеет автоматически и безостановочно отправлять запросы (но наверно стоит в логах посмотреть, какие именно запросы, чтобы было похоже на юзеров)

Понял, спасибо, это уже пробовали.  Может есть какие то способы  ловить причины зависания докера? Инспектор пробовали, логи записывали, нигде ничего не отображается.
